# Report application

Tags: applications

Not sure if this is the proper place to ask this question, but here it goes.

Where/how can I report an Android application that tells it's users to click on its AdMob ads?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you thinking of reporting it for?

If you're going to report it because this is against [AdMob's Terms of Use](http://www.admob.com/home/terms) (I haven't checked, but this sort of thing is normally against most ad network's rules. Then they don't seem to be open to much Contact from people without Admob logins, but you can try their [Contact](http://www.admob.com/home/contact) page, which has Twitter and Facebook accounts listed.

If you think that this makes the app itself annoying, then find its page on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) and write a review and give a rating reflecting that, to warn other people who may be thinking about using the app.

[image]

If this causes a real problem with the app, or seems to be malicious in some way, then if you have the app installed, you can go into the Play Store on your device, go into the My Apps list, find the app, scroll to the bottom of its page, and then you should see a "Flag as inappropriate" link to report the app to Google.

[image]